# DB query language design

Tags: language-design

What are some good (academic) resources to learn about database query language design? I'm specifically interested in document databases, but all I can find is about XQuery and it's unclear to me what trade-off were mede there.

Comment: Not an expert, but I guess there's datalog and linq. I think the deeper issue is query language is ultimately tied to the database type, so you are in some sense asking the age-old sql vs no-sql question again.

Comment: Requests for off-site resources [are off-topic here](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/261/89) ─ if there is something specific you want to learn from those resources, you could ask it directly instead.